# issue with jquery handling html5 elements loaded by jinja (django)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, html

I am trying to create a media player with django and while jquery is able to pick up the first track, it is not able to pick up the rest

html

```
{% if tracksurl %}
{% for tracks in tracksurl %}
    <audio class="playsong" src="{{tracks}}"></audio>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<button id="play">PLAY</button>
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
<button id="next">NEXT</button>
```

jquery

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var audioArray = document.getElementsByClassName('playsong');
var nowPlaying = audioArray[i=0];
nowPlaying.load(); 

$('#play').click(function() {
    nowPlaying.play();
})
$('#stop').click(function() {
    nowPlaying.pause();
})

$('#next').click(function() {
    $.each($('audio.playsong'), function() {
        this.pause();
    });
    i++;
    nowPlaying.load();
    nowPlaying.play();
})

})

</script>
```

tracksurl is a list and currently holds more than 1 url to an audio, and the play button is able to play the first audio track, however when clicked on next, it still only plays the first track

Comment: JavaScript has the rsther intransparent feature to overwrite node attributed that have the same name as the I'd of the node. You should try to give unique ids that do not match the function names to the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is that the value of `nowPlaying` is initialized, but it is never really updated (the index `i` is updated, but not the actual value of `nowPlaying`), so it will always be the same song (the first one).

So just add this after the `i++` line:

```
nowPlaying = audioArray[i];
```

Now, there is another issue with the code: the value of `i` is being increased without checking if it exceeds the length of the array of audios. That means that the player will break when trying to access the lenght+1 item.

To fix that, update the value of `i` taking into consideration the length of the array using a module operation:

```
i = ++i % audioArray.length;
```

So once all that is fixed, the code would look like this and work fine (demo audio files from MDN and W3Schools):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var audioArray = document.getElementsByClassName('playsong');
  var nowPlaying = audioArray[i=0];
  nowPlaying.load(); 

  $('#play').click(function() {
    nowPlaying.play();
  })
  $('#stop').click(function() {
    nowPlaying.pause();
  })

  $('#next').click(function() {
    $.each($('audio.playsong'), function() {
      this.pause();
    });
    i = ++i % audioArray.length;
    nowPlaying = audioArray[i];
    nowPlaying.load();
    nowPlaying.play();
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio class="playsong" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3"></audio>
<audio class="playsong" src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg"></audio>

<button id="play">PLAY</button>
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
<button id="next">NEXT</button>
```